# Accessing what's shown in camera without taking a picture

Tags: html, web, camera

Using a webapp, I know how to open the camera app on a mobile phone. I want to know how to access what is shown in the camera, such as if there exists an image similar to an image in a pre-stored database.
I want to do this without taking a picture an analyzing it.

Comment: Not possible in iOS. Can't speak to Android.

Comment: The OP wants to know if it can be done via a web app.

Comment: @thetypist I *can* read. It is, as I noted, not possible in iOS. You can do it with a native app, but iOS Safari [does not support the necessary API](http://caniuse.com/#search=getUserMedia) for webapps. It *appears* to be supported in the very latest Android versions, although as I said I can't speak to if it works.